# Why am I committing a bunch of desktop.ini files despite .gitignore?

Tags: git, git-commit

I don't understand what happened. I did

```
git add .
git commit
```

and suddenly I see a list of a bunch of desktop.ini files committed.

(I don't understand why previous commits did not get any of them, and what might have suddenly changed, but that's an aside)

So, I undid the commit

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

Added a line to .gitignore:

```
./**/desktop.ini
```

And did another

```
git add .
git commit -m "test"
```

Still adding a bunch of desktop.ini. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This was happening to me because I put my workdir in a **google drive**. I would not recommend doing this, as there can be plenty issues because of that, for example `packaging` or `building` software can fail because files are/aren't added/removed quick enough, or because permission issues.

Answer (score 10):

Just write this simpler thing into your `.gitignore`:

```
desktop.ini
```

You could also do

```
**/desktop.ini
```

but it has the same effect. See `man gitignore` for details.

Then do something like this to get files out of the index:

```
git reset --soft
git add .
```

Comment: This could've been a useful comment, but it does not answer the question at all.

Comment: Oh, I see, I might have misunderstood the question. However, it is definitely part of the full answer, because `./**/desktop.ini` simply does not work (tested it twice now).

Comment: Huh. That's a good point. If you can edit your answer to make it more complete -- preferably not by simply copying Matthieu's answer -- I'll be happy to change my -1 to a +1. (Existing votes are locked until you make edit anyway.)

Answer (score 4):

Your `git reset --soft` did not reset the index: you canceled the commit, but the files are still in the index (i.e. "added"). So, when you committed again, you got the same commit with the same files.

You wanted to to `git reset --mixed` (or omit `--mixed` which is the default anyway) to reset the index (but not the working tree).

Comment: Thank you. Just looked up "git reset --soft" and it says: `"Does not touch the index file or the working tree at all (but resets the head to <commit>, just like all modes do)."  ` What does it mean? Where was the head before this command?

Comment: HEAD is "the current commit". The index is the list of files to be committed (together with their content).

Comment: @ТаняТ. It may help if you think of `git reset` as having several different (somewhat related, but quite different in goal) jobs: one is to reset the index; another is to change the SHA-1 that is set as "the current branch".  With `--mixed` it does *both* of these, and if you only wanted the index reset, you tell it to it re-set the branch `HEAD` points to, to where `HEAD` points to now, i.e., change it to what it already has.  That way the only *real* change is to reset the index.  (And "where HEAD is now" is also the default, so to tell it that, you just don't tell it anything!)

Comment: I did git reset and a bunch of other commands, and it changed my directory tree. Trying to figure out what I did wrong